# submit form on keyup on elements added dynamically via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form-submit, onkeyup

I have 2 forms with the same ids.

I want when you type a key in the text area with id=`ingevuldNotitie` then javascript will submit the form. Is there a way to do this and so how?

```
<div id="response">
  <div id="child_response">

    <form action="test.php" method="post" id="notitieForm" onsubmit="return notitieOpslaan();">
      <input type="text" id="clientNotitieDatum" value="2022-10-17" name="clientNotitieDatum" hidden="">
      <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="ingevuldNotitie" name="ingevuldNotitie"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" name="clientNotitie" value="Notitie opslaan">
    </form>

    <form action="test.php" method="post" id="notitieForm" onsubmit="return notitieOpslaan();">
      <input type="text" id="clientNotitieDatum" value="2022-10-18" name="clientNotitieDatum" hidden="">
      <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="ingevuldNotitie" name="ingevuldNotitie"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" name="clientNotitie" value="Notitie opslaan">
    </form>

  </div>
</div>

<script>

  // I tried this
  $("#response").bind("keyup", function () {   
    $(this).closest('[name=clientNotitieDatum]').submit(); 
  });

  // And I tried this
  $("text[name='ingevuldNotitie']").bind("keyup", function () {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the elements are dynamically added via ajax, you should use `$(document).on('keyup', "textarea[name='ingevuldNotitie']", function() {`.

Alo, in your `form`s `onsubmit`, add an argument to the function:

```
onsubmit="return notitieOpslaan(this);"
```

And use that argument to get the form's data, such as `clientNotitieDatum`.

See working demo below:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="response">
  <div id="child_response">

    <form action="test.php" method="post" id="notitieForm" onsubmit="return notitieOpslaan(this);">
      <input type="text" id="clientNotitieDatum" value="2022-10-17" name="clientNotitieDatum" hidden="">
      <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="ingevuldNotitie" name="ingevuldNotitie"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" name="clientNotitie" value="Notitie opslaan">
    </form>

    <form action="test.php" method="post" id="notitieForm" onsubmit="return notitieOpslaan(this);">
      <input type="text" id="clientNotitieDatum" value="2022-10-18" name="clientNotitieDatum" hidden="">
      <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="ingevuldNotitie" name="ingevuldNotitie"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" name="clientNotitie" value="Notitie opslaan">
    </form>

  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).on('keyup', "textarea[name='ingevuldNotitie']", function() {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
  });
  
  function notitieOpslaan(theForm) {
    var clientNotitieDatum = theForm['clientNotitieDatum'].value;
    console.log('form would have been submitted', clientNotitieDatum);
    return false;
  }  
</script>
```

Comment: It is so weird if I put your code in my file it doesn't work. But when I make a new project than your code works. Soo weird.

Comment: What makes you say it doesn't work? Any error?

Comment: No error just nothing this doesn't even work: console.log('form would have been submitted');

Comment: Do you have `onsubmit="return notitieOpslaan();">` on the form?

Comment: Yes I have that

Comment: Hm. The demo above works for you, right? Maybe you want to compare what you have line by line to the demo above. http://www.mergely.com/editor?ws=1&wl=1 could be helpful for that

Comment: Yes the demo above works. Maybe is this the problem I dont know but <div id="response"></div> and <div id="child_response"></div> are from a ajax request could there maybe be the problem with.

Comment: First I in de ajax if it is succes I will first remove and than add $( "#child_response" ).remove();
          
 $("#response").append('<div id="child_response">'+response+'</div>');

Comment: Ah, yes, that could be the issue. Try this instead, then: `$(document).on('keyup', "textarea[name='ingevuldNotitie']", function() {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
  });`

Comment: Yes now it works but before this when you just pressed the submit button my function worked correct. My function was this notitieOpslaan(){
    var clientNotitieDatum = event.currentTarget['clientNotitieDatum'].value; 
  }    Now it says: Uncaught TypeError: event.currentTarget.clientNotitieDatum is undefined. Do you know any fix for that

Comment: Yes: change the `onsubmit` of your forms to add an argument to the function call: `onsubmit="return notitieOpslaan(this);" `, and then use it inside the `notitieOpslaan` by adding a parameter `function notitieOpslaan(theForm) { var clientNotitieDatum = theForm['clientNotitieDatum'].value; }`. I have rewritten the answer to address all of this.

Comment: I love you so much man thank you!